# Fill several form fields when user clicks suggestions

Tags: jquery

When a user posts a form, I validate an address split into several fields. If the address is not found I show a list with suggested spots that might be useful, those suggestions look like links.

What I want is that if the user clicks on one link, several form fields get filled using JQuery. The fake links can contain different information, but I'm not sure how to format and parse it using JQuery. I was thinking about using hidden fields, but not sure if this is the right approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store the values within the link (anchor) element itself. At the start of your page, assign the associated data to each link with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data). Then, you could assign one "suggestion" [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) handler to all the links.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // assign suggestion data
    $('#link1').data('field1', 'foo');
    $('#link1').data('field2', 'bar');

    $('#link2').data('field1', 'baz');
    $('#link2').data('field2', 'qux');

    // bind suggestion click handler
    $('a.suggestion').bind('click', function() {
        $('#field1').val($(this).data('field1'));
        $('#field2').val($(this).data('field2'));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" />
<input type="text" id="field2" />

<a href="#" id="link1" class="suggestion">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" class="suggestion">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: Only problem I see is that data method is not cross-platform with XHTML & unfortunately visitor's major browser is IE. any other idea? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I didn't know if the IE compatibility note about data in XML documents applied to HTML or not. (I don't have IE, so I couldn't test.) If you're really looking to avoid hidden fields and the like, you could just create a global JS array/object with all the values in it, though it would be markedly less cool. :-)

Comment: No problem, I still have to test it with IE, using Linux for development, makes it a pain. I agree with you this is way more cool than having a global JS object. Anyways I'm marking your answer as accepted, thanks.

Comment: I forgot to say that this code actually works with XHTML under IE 7 & IE8, so they didn't refer to XHTML :)